# Linux, how to execute an executable / non-executable file?

Tags: linux, shell

In the Linux, how to execute an executable / non-executable file ?

```
. myfile.sh  --- works, why?
sh myfile.sh -- doesn't work, why ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Easy there, `. myfile.sh` is not `./myfile.sh`. The dot-space is actually an alias for the `source` command: `source myfile.sh`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happens when it "doesn't work"

Comment: You need to show the error messages, but turning on my ESP, your script probably uses bash-specific features that `sh` doesn't understand.

Comment: What glenn jackman sez.  I can't help if I don't know exactly what "doesn't work" means.  Did you get an error message?  Did it not do what you expected it to do?  What?

Answer (score 3):

`sh ./myfile.sh` should work though

Answer (score 1):

`./myfile.sh` --> if the file is `+x`

Otherwise it wont run.