# How can I get stdio output when running application as root?

Tags: c++, linux, cout

I'm trying to run my application as root because I need to access low level hardware on my computer.

When I run the command:

```
./application_name
```

...it works, except gives an error that it needs root. However, when I run this:

```
sudo ./application_name
```

...I get no terminal ouput.

I've tested that every time that I run an executable on Linux as root, it doesn't print anything to terminal. How can I fix this?

Edit: somewhat of a test case provided (mobile so can't type out much):

```
sudo g++ test.cpp -o executable
sudo chmod +x executable
```

This works on Debian:

```
./executable
```

This doesn't:

```
sudo ./executable
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: Close voters: why is this off topic but this on topic? Both are about executing code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817060/creating-executable-files-in-linux

Comment: That question is **five** years old and was posted at a time when the posting guidelines were quite different. The existence of a very old question does not mean it is OK to post a similar one.

Comment: Apparently that's how the application behaves. Some applications just don't produce output (`/bin/true`, for example). We know nothing at all about the application, so we can't help you figure out why it's not producing any output. Try `sudo echo hello`; it should print `hello`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious some other related ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080835/running-an-executable-in-mac-terminal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467031/at-command-is-not-executed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812145/linux-how-to-execute-an-executable-non-executable-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625580/difference-between-executable-and-executable and they aren't closed.

Comment: Note that you don't terminate the output with a newline.  Adding `<< endl` or including a newline in the string to be printed would improve the chances of the output being printed.  That doesn't really explain the difference between root and non-root behaviour.

Comment: Why are you running `g++` with `sudo`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler AFAIK buffers are flushed when the process dies.

Comment: g++ already makes the executable executable: You don't need chmod. Anyways, can you check stdout is open? Does checking the stream state reveal something?

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is really strange. Root permissions for that application should have no effect on std output. 
For example, I made a simple test, a "hello world" that I ran as root on Debian OS and I had output in terminal.

A simple test to convince yourself that you should have the output, is to make a redirect to a file. For example sudo ./executable > output.txt and you'll see that everything should be OK.

Note that it should be strange if you don't have output from a simple "hello world".